# Remove a div with ID from the_content WordPress

Tags: the-content

I was trying to remove a div having some ID from the_content WordPress.
I am trying to achieve something like this

```
jQuery( "#some_id" ).remove();
```

but on server side,

I don't have a clue how I can do this on server side within the_content filter hook.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {


    $content.find('#some_id').remove();


    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had posted same question on Stackoverflow as well, and below answer worked for me. Maybe someone else need this too.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43743269/2829625

Answer (score 0):

with the_content filter hook you can modify the content using PHP [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) search and replace

```
function remove_specific_wrapper($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('#<div[^>]*id="some_id"[^>]*>.*?</div>#is', '', $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_specific_wrapper');
```